# Print data contents of HTML Object tag without external packages

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, dom

I want to print the PDF without opening in a new tab.

I have a PDF embedded in an HTML Object tag like so:

```
<>
  <object id="documentObject" data={fileSrc} type={fileType} height="100%" width="100%" />
</>
```

I want to print this file with the built in browser print function (window.print()?)
I am using Reactjs and the current method I am trying is the following:

```
const { fileName, fileSrc } = props;
  const handleClick = (): void => {
    const element: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('documentObject');
    if (element !== null) {
      //print logic here
      console.log(element);
    }
  };

  return (
    <StyledDocumentButton
      variant={props.variant ?? 'contained'}
      color="primary"
      onClick={handleClick}
      size={props.size}
      sx={props.sx}
    >
      {props.text ?? 'Download'}
    </StyledDocumentButton>
  );
};
```

I have tried focusing and printing the element, but that does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When a client **downloads a web page to view** in their editor, the word strings <"object"> etc. that is in their browser html text editor/viewer is in viewer mode, thus that text is not displayed:-

[image]

This means that IF they have the editors pdf extended viewer switched on, then they as client need to invoke secured printing of the contents, It makes no difference where the content was remote or now local the outcome is exactly the same.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

***However IF you try to print (JavaScripted or otherwise) their HTML then that's exactly what you will be offering, the unseen HTML surrounds*** IF scripting is allowed by the editor, then it may without script blocking, on occasion open the pdf contents elsewhere but the script still cannot invoke running a printout without user control of the external resource.

[image]
[image]